# Как проверить пересекает ли сфера хотя бы одну из координат?

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Мне дана сущность типа `SphereEntity`, которая имеет следующие поля:

- `int radius`;
- `Point point(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, int zCoordinate).`

Необходимо создать метод `boolean isCrossThoughtAnyAxis(SphereEntity sphere)`, проверяющий касается(пересекает) ли сфера хотя бы одну координатную ось.

Из уравнения (1) сферы я попытался вывести формулы для определения этих самых точек. Что-то получилось(2), но я ума не приложу каким образом это задать в коде.

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья, прошу вас не думать, что я обнаглевший дурачок, который хочет при первой неудаче получить готовое: сидел над этим не мало часов, но, к моему большому сожалению, ничего в голову не лезет.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Лучше б школу не прогуливали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы хотел пояснить более подробно, и начать, как начали вы - с уравнения сферы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что такое ось X? Это множество точек, для которых

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит, чтлбы получить точки пересечения сферы с осью X, нужно решить уравнение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но слева стоит величина, которая не может быть отрицательна. Значит, решение сушествует тогда и только тогда, когда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А точки равны соответственно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за такое чудесное разъяснение, дорогой Mikhailo!

Comment: "Что такое ось X? ... x = y = 0" - дальше не читал.

Comment: @Igor И выставил себя дураком :) Прочел бы до конца - понял бы, что опечатка.

Comment: @Igor специально для вас оставил еще одну - "чтлбы" - ну, чтоб вы себя почувствовали великим и ужасным по сравнению с моей ничтожностью. Вашему комплексу неполноценности можно только позавидовать :)

Answer (score 1):

Пример для оси `x`.

Точка оси `x`, ближайшая к центру сферы - это точка с координатами `(x0,0,0)`. Согласны?

Если ось `x` пересекает сферу, то и точка `(x0,0,0)` обязана лежать внутри шара, то есть расстояние от `(x0,0,0)` до `(x0,y0,z0)` должно быть меньше `R`

Другими словами, ось `x` пересекает сферу тогда и только тогда`y0*y0 + z0*z0 < R*R`

В случае, когда `y0*y0 + z0*z0 == R*R` сфера касается оси `x`.

Comment: Благодарю вас за отклик, дорогой Pak Uula!